# updating parent component on child reactquill onChange() in component with componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

Hi am using reactquill in my child component and i want to update my parent state when users type. currently i am doing it using onBlur() but that is not what the users want.

this is my **child component**.

```
    public componentWillReceiveProps(newProps): void {
         //console.log(newProps, "new props");
         this.setState({
           text: newProps.value
         });
       }

       public setProps() {
         //console.log("set props", this.state.text);
         if(this.state.text === "<p><br></p>"){
          this.props.onChange("");
         } else {
          this.props.onChange(this.state.text);
         }

       }

      public handleChange(value) {
        this.setState({ text: value });
        //console.log("update props of parent", value);
        //this.props.onChange(value);
      }

public render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div className="text-editor" onBlur= {this.setProps}>
              <ReactQuill value={this.state.text} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        //onKeyPress={this.handleKeyDown}
                        //onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
                        onBlur= {this.setProps} 
                        modules={this.modules} 
                        formats={this.formats}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

and this i from my **Parent Componen**t calling the child;

```
 public renderEditableAnswer = (cellInfo) => {
   return (
      <div>
        <QnAAnswerInput 
            value={cellInfo.original.Answer} 
            onChange={data => this.updateQnAAnswer(data, cellInfo)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

public updateQnAAnswer = (data, cellInfo) => {
    let qnaItems = [...this.state.qnaItems];
    let index;
    if(cellInfo.original.Id != null){
      index = _.findIndex(qnaItems,d => d.Id == cellInfo.original.Id);
    } else {
       index = _.findIndex(qnaItems,d => d.identifier == cellInfo.original.identifier);
    }

    if(this.getText(data) !== this.getText(cellInfo.original.Answer)){
      let item = {
        ...qnaItems[index],
        Answer: data, 
      };
      qnaItems[index] = item;
      this.setState({ qnaItems });

      this.updateActionHistory(item,index);
    }
  }
```

this component is inside a ReactTable cell, hence the cellInfo. Note that i do have one functionality in the parent component that would add a new row to the table which needs to have an empty values for the child component. i noticed that without the WillReceiveProps method, my "Add New Empty Row" is not working.

In my current code, if i comment out the this.props.onChange(this.state.text); inside the handleChange method, typing inside the editor fires the componentWillReceiveProps (iterating through all my reacttable values, which is a lot) which renders a delay in typing a text. and this is not good.

is there anyway for me to update my parent state with onChange without having typing delays?

Answer (score 1):

Use only `componentDidMount()` and `componentDidUpdate()` the other life cycle methods are bad practice.
You have a typing delay because of `componentWillReceiveProps`, never use it. I do not understand your code, there are no names and you have unnecessary code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onBlur= {this.setProps} in div ,

call it in componentDidUpdate

```
  componentDidUpdate = ( prevProps , prevState) =>{
    if(prevState.editorHtml !== this.state.editorHtml )
      this.setProps()
  }
```

Do you have any better solution?